# How to change the color of \href links... for real

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I would like web links generated by the `\href` command to be colored in my Beamer presentation.  Passing the `colorlinks` option to hyperref leads to navigation links within the PDF receiving (default, ugly) colors.  OTOH, without passing that option hyperref doesn't apply any color to links at all.

```
\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=links} % Does not apply color to href's
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=links} % href's are correct, but navigation links are magenta
```

Is there a way to tell `hyperref` to apply a color only to links generated by `\href` (or `\url`), and leave navigation links alone?  (I know that I could define a command `\myhref` to do the color-changing manually; I am looking for a solution that uses the built-in facilities of `hyperref`/`beamer`.)

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. For example, your other possibly other `hyperref` options and specifically (`x`)`color` options are not clear here. So it's hard to work out.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You could add `\hypersetup{linkcolor=}` in order to remove the coloring of internal links used for navigation purposes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{frame}
  \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}\\
  \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13423/how-to-color-href-links-in-beamer}{Your question}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

works fine for me as you can see in the headline - the navigation link is colored in the default gray tone, while the links are colored in the desired blue.

Comment: Perfect -- the blank specification of `linkcolor` was exactly the kind of trick I was looking for.

Comment: It did not work for me. I had to input `linkcolor=white`.

Comment: I finally chose `linkcolor=gray` because of this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21696/

Comment: Dude... thank you so much. This was driving me crazy. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 16):

If you're looking for something simpler, here's another alternative.

```
\href{https://www.url.com/}{\color{blue}{\underline{Demo}}}
```

[image]