# Empty Table of Contents with Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

The first slide in the following `beamer` presentation is empty:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{slide1}
slide 1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I include `slide1` in the table of contents?

Comment: The table of contents includes _sections_ only. add `\section{Something}` before your slide to see something in the table of contents

Comment: @Seamus: sections and subsections etc., to be precise.

Comment: @MArtin yes. What I meant was _not_ frames...

Comment: @Seamus: Could you make that an answer?

Comment: In my case, it was because of this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13423/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table of contents includes *sections* only. Add `\section{Something}` before your slide to see something in the table of contents:

```
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{slide1}
slide 1
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
```