# Changing moderncv link color of href

Tags: moderncv

I'm using moderncv and by default the links I set via `\href{}{}` seem to have the same color as normal text. How do I change their color?

I tried to add (according to [How to change the color of \href links... for real](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13423/how-to-change-the-color-of-href-links-for-real)):

```
\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}
```

The document failed building with

```
Undefined control sequence. l.33 \hypersetup 
{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}
```

Another failed try was:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
```

That gave the error:

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.
```

Comment: Are you really getting errors about undefined hypersetup or an error because `links` is not a valid color?

Comment: @Johannes_B : I copied the error that the Overleaf console gave me.

Comment: @Christian: Is `\hypersetup` used before `\usepackage{hyperref}` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It seems like \usepackage{hyperref} is used in the .cls and I try to use \hypersetup in the .tex

Comment: @Christian the proble is that `hyperref` is loaded with `\AtEndPreamble` so one can try `\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}` after `\begin{document}` but I am not sure it will work.

Comment: `PassOptionsToPackage`

Comment: This is another example of a `template` being smart but actually making it much more difficult for the user to change stuff. Fixed-output (given) vs. non-fixed output (what the op wants)

Answer (score 17):

Here is a solution.

`hyperref` is loaded at the end of the preamble with `\AtEndPreamble`. We need to pass `colorlinks,linkcolor=true` options to the package, one way is to make it global `\documentclass[colorlinks,linkcolor=true]{moderncv}` and than 
`\hypersetup{urlcolor=thecolor}` after `\begin{document}`

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,colorlinks,linkcolor=true]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{Some}{One}
\title{some title} 
\address{10, address}{city}{Country}
\email{someone@myemail.com}
\homepage{www.mypage.com}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\cventry{2015--2016}{Recherche}{Bla bla}{Foo bar}{More bla bla}%
{Last bla bla}

\cvitem{bla bla}{Foo bar}

\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275848/71471}{Defaut color}

\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=links}
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275848/71471}{Your color}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Then to prevent links in your footer from being altered, add `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` before the `\clearpage`

Comment: I get an error with `linkcolor=true` while compiling, but e.g. `linkcolor=cyan` works alright.