# how to create an href reference with moderncv and having the latex font instead of the default one?

Tags: moderncv

There is this command, to create an href link

```
\href{this is my text}{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275848/71471}
```

I want to change the `this is my text` to a `rmfamily` font (see the first line in the [screen capture](https://i1.wp.com/texblog.org/Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/latex-sans-serif-font1.png) as an example)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `\href` have two arguments: `\href{URL}{text}` and write text in a LaTeX font. Please explain what do you mean.

Comment: hi @Fran, question updated.

Comment: The Sans Serif family is in the second line, not in the first. Simply add  `\sffamily` to the text part.

Comment: @Fran what is the name of the first line font, please? This is the one I want actually. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try with `\rmfamily`

Comment: hi @Fran, please add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\href` take two arguments: the first is the URL to be linked and the second the text showed in the link, so it should be:

```
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275848/71471}{this is my text}
```

The command do not change the font style in any way, so often it will be already in roman (serifed) font family, that is the default text style in most document classes.

Otherwise, you can change using `\textrm{<text>}` or `\rmfamily <text>` since the braces of the argument limit the scope of the command:

```
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275848/71471}{\textrm{this is my text}}
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275848/71471}{\rmfamily this is my text}
```